# MySql Store Procedure Search Like

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have search field with param called "query" this param will search different columns for a match. It works but the query has to match exactly in order to get a return. I have tried using '%' but I dont think I am using it correctly. Im trying to have more generatic search.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `client_search_reps`(IN offset INT, IN row_count INT, IN query varchar(100))
BEGIN

    SELECT
            U.Id,
            U.RoleId,
            UP.FirstName,
            UP.LastName,
            UP.FileUrl,
            L.City,
            L.Zip,
            CP.Name,
            CP.Url,
            CP.Phone,
            CP.Email,
            P.ProductOne,
            P.ProductTwo,
            P.ProductThree,
            P.ProductFour,


        FROM user_profiles AS UP
        LEFT JOIN users AS U ON U.Id = UP.UserId
        LEFT JOIN location AS L ON  L.UserProfileId = UP.UserId
        LEFT JOIN company_profile AS CP ON CP.UserId = UP.UserId
        LEFT JOIN products AS P ON P.UserId = U.Id
        
        WHERE UP.FirstName LIKE query || UP.LastName LIKE query || CP.Name LIKE query 
        || CP.Phone LIKE query || CP.Email LIKE query
        
        LIMIT offset, row_count;
            
END
```

Below is my React.Js code just in case it helps understand my issue.

```
searchAccount = (query) => {
    profileServices
      .searchAccounts(0, query)
      .then(this.searchSuccess)
      .catch(this.searchError);
  };

  searchSuccess = (data) => {
    let accounts = data.item.pagedItems;
    this.setState({
      mappedProfiles: accounts.map(this.mapSearch),
      currentItems: data.item.totalCount,
    });
  };

  searchError = (data) => {
    swal({
      title: "Search is Broad",
      text: "Search by: Company Name, Phone, or Email",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    });
  };

  onSearch = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        query: value,
      };
    });
  };

  clearSearch = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        query: "",
      };
    });
    // this.getProfiles(0);
  };

  search = () => {
    if (this.state.query.length > 0 ? this.searchAccount(this.state.query) : 0);
    this.setState({
      searchModal: true,
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add SQL's wildcard character to the `query`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE client_search_reps(
offset INT, 
row_count INT, 
query varchar(100)
)
BEGIN

SET query = CONCAT('%', query, '%');
...
```

Btw, it's better to use standard `OR` instead of non-standard `||` (the `||` is deprecated in MySQL 8.0.17 and has different behavior depending on the sql_mode being used in all versions).